# Java Check user input against variables in another class

Tags: java

I am building an easy Knock Knock game.  I have it finished but I would like to add a small feature.  It is currently set to accept only a few words/phrases as the correct response and everything else it produces an "error" of sorts.  I want to create a class with a list of acceptable works or phrases and have the users input checked against that class.
Here is the test class I created to play with.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class test 
    {
        static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

    System.out.println("Choose a word");
    String userEntry = sc.next().toLowerCase();

    if (userEntry.equals(test1.*))
    {
        System.out.println("We found a match");
    }

    else if (!userEntry.equals(test1.*))
    {
        System.out.println("We did not find a match");
    }


}
```

}

The code is of the class that will house the variables.

```
    public class test1 
    {

public static String a = "yes";

public static String b = "hello";

public static String c = "boo";

    }
```

In the first class, I tried using a wild card to call all of the variables in the class but it produces an error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't 'call all the variables' like that, it's simply not valid Java syntax. You might want to look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a wildcard search like that in Java.

You really don't need another class, you can just put all the words/phrases in a List and check against the List.

**Example**:

```
import java.util.*;

public class test
{
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // add all the words you need into this array
    static String [] wordArr = new String[] { "yes", "hello", "boo" };

    // this converts the array to a List
    static final List<String> WORDS 
          = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(wordArr));

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Choose a word");
        String userEntry = sc.next().toLowerCase();

        // check if the word is in the list
        if (WORDS.contains(userEntry))
        {
            System.out.println("We found a match");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("We did not find a match");
        }
    }
}
```

**Side Note**: You should consider creating the Scanner in the main method and close the scanner when you are done with it.

Comment: If you initiate the array at the class level (like above), can the array variable be used in multiple classes?

Comment: Yes. The simplest way would be to just make the array public, then you can access it from other classes with `test.wordArr` Since it is static you don't need to make an instance of test just to access it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class   test1 
        {
    public static list<String> addElement(){
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("yes");
    list.add("boo"); 
    list.add("hello");
    }

 }


class test{
public static void main(String[] args0)
{
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String match=sc.next();
ArrayList<String> list=test1.addElement();
for(String test : list)
{
  if(test.equels(match)
   print("we have found match");
  else
  print("no match found"):
}
}
}
```